# Using external Android apps as dynamic Fragments

Tags: android, dynamic, android-fragments

I've read several posts about changing Fragments dynamically using a Fragment transaction, but they show instantiating a Fragment class and using that in the transaction. But how about loading Fragments that are not part of the owning project, but are instead external apps (they are all FragmentActivities).

What I have is a "main" application that is much like an email inbox, but the "inbox" may have *n* different kinds of "messages". I have a list of package names for apps that "main" supports (I dynamically discover them from packageManager), so I know what kind of "message" I tap on, and then I fire off an Intent (using the package name) to load its external app. What I'm trying to do is load that external app into a dual fragment layout.

Any suggestions out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how about loading Fragments that are not part of the owning project, but are instead external apps (they are all FragmentActivities).

This is not possible, sorry.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the confirmation!